# Issue downloading and Installing Anaconda - Error "No such file or directory" running downloaded bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, amazon-ec2

I am trying to follow [Getting Spark, Python, and Jupyter Notebook running on Amazon EC2](https://medium.com/@josemarcialportilla/getting-spark-python-and-jupyter-notebook-running-on-amazon-ec2-dec599e1c297), but I'm stuck on step 4.

This part works. The file `Anaconda3–4.1.1-Linux-x86_64.sh` gets downloaded to `/home/ubuntu` (home directory)

```
wget http://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.1.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

This does not work:

```
bash Anaconda3–4.1.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Error message:

```
bash: Anaconda3–4.1.1-Linux-x86_64.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check that your terminal is active in the same directory as the downloaded file (though it should since wget will by default download the file in the active directory, so if you did both command one after another it should be fine).

The path your terminal is in is indicated like so : `username@machinename:[path]$`

In your case, it might be : `username@machinename:~$`. The ~ is a shortcut for your **home** directory

- check that you indeed received the file by browsing in your file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I just chose the latest version in the Anaconda installer archive

1. Go to https://repo.continuum.io/archive/
2. Check out what the latest version is
3. Enter `wget http://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-x.x-Linux-x86_64.sh` in the shell with x.x being the latest version
4. Enter `bash Anaconda3-x.x-Linux-x86_64.sh`